# How to set recurring payment in Braintree using API without creating any plan?

Tags: php, paypal, braintree

I have a web application for provide different types of packages for customers. I want set Braintree payment gateway. I have no idea how to set recurring payment in braintree.

For all customer billing amount different based on packages and also billing period is different for each customer, So anyone can help me how can I implement recurring payment in Braintree?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you have more questions, you can always [get in touch with our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Check out the [Braintree Recurring Billing Guide](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+php/guides/recurring-billing) for how to do recurring billing with Braintree.

Basically, you need to have a plan and a customer (with a payment method), and you associate them together by creating a subscription.

Subscriptions can [override basically all settings of their plan](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+php/sdk/server/recurring-billing/create), so it is possible to use one Braintree plan to represent many different plans on your side.

Comment: Looks like it's not possible to create a Recurring Billing Plan from API, is that correct? Is there a possibility of exposing this as a feature, or is this some kind of security measure or somehting?

Comment: @aaronbauman You should reach out to our support team, but generally it's not necessary because the number of plans is very small, and addons and discounts are used to customize subscriptions.